# Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, configuration, cumulative-update

I installed the August-2016 CU updates and then I upgraded the farm solutions after that i can't deploy any solutions in SharePoint 2013 by using visual studio  ?I got this error message **Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.**

Answer (score 2):

IISReset & Timer Service restart helped me in this case as described in this  [blogspot](http://sharepoint1on1.blogspot.de/2014/04/sharepoint-error-occurred-in-deployment.html)